# Trying to set up python for Azure on a Mac using vscode but getting `Import "azure.common.credentials" could not be resolved`

Tags: python-3.x, azure, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I am new to Python and Azure scripting...and Mac (somewhat). I am trying to create a simple python script so I can create a set of Azure resources I use in a project. I followed [these directions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to set up vscode and I loosely followed [these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/resource-manager-python-resources-and-groups/manage-azure-resources-and-resource-groups-with-python/) to get started with the Azure commands.  Loosely, so I could ensure I knew what was happening. I did not pull down the repo. I am getting an `Import "azure.common.credentials" could not be resolved` error on the following line:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
```

In setting up the vscode/python environment, [I selected the 3.7.3 interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_select-a-python-interpreter). I did not pull down the github repo or run the `pip install -r requirements.txt`, again just to make sure I could do this from scratch and understand how these things work together.

When I run `pip install azure` from the command line it seems to default to the python 2.7 installation on the Mac, [which is deprecated but I think required on the Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935752/problems-with-the-python-version-on-macos-bigsur).

Do I need to do the pip install azure for 3.7.3? If so how do I do that?

Comment: For systems with both Python 2 and 3, use `pip3 install azure`

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley. The install seems to work using this, but the message in vscode still reads Import "azure.mgmt.resource" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Comment: Sometimes you must install more than one library. Try this one: `pip3 install azure-common`.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnHanley. Looks like it's installed. However I got this message "Requirement already satisfied: azure-common in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages" and my settings.json has: "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3". I'm wondering if I am installing in a different environment.

Comment: Open a macOS terminal window. Type "which python3". Open a terminal in Visual Code. Type "which python3". Are they the same? Note: I do not recommend installing python, libraries, etc in the system. Instead set up a Python virtual environment. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: From macOS terminal: "/usr/local/bin/python3" and from vscode terminal: "/usr/local/bin/python3". The "pip3 install azure-common" command earlier had outputted this line: "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages".

Comment: No more ideas. I recommend using a Python virtual environment so you do not have these types of problems.